# Importing specific rows of Data from Text file into different array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having some survey data which is in text file. All the data need to be put into different array

The example for the data is like:

```
C 1 1000 1000                                                                               
C 2 1010.72 1005.04                                                                       
C 3 1004.68 1009.53                                                               

B 1 2 25.1200 2                                                                  
B 2 3 143.2250 2                                                                   
B 3 1 243.4840 2                                                                 

D 1 2 11.843 0.038                                                                
D 2 3 7.531 0.038                                                                
D 3 1 10.613 0.038
```

Now all I want to put all the data into different array which start with different alphabet. C for Coordinate, B for bearing and D for distance. The data will increases based on how much data that user entered.I am extremely new to Java and as such am having great difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public class Importer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path file = Paths.get("C:/temp/mydata.txt");
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file);
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line.startsWith("C ")) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above the source a `package ...;` and many `import ... .Files;` and such.
An IDE will help.